# Stop bug reports in HTA ( without admin privileges )

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, hta, bug-reporting

I'm using HTA with frames, the left frame controls the main frame and show pages in it (like a navigation panel), for example: You press the 'google' link on the left and it opens it on the main window. (This isn't the primary HTA's purpose, but I just simplify it to explain)

Now the problem is when I'm trying to open a web page with bug reports - The HTA is keep informing me about the page's bugs and sometimes the page even doesn't function properly. (The bug reports are not about pages that I created!)
The same pages works perfectly in IE.

It is important to mention as in the title, that I or any of the HTA's users doesn't have admin privileges in the system.

I googled it for a long time, but never found a solution, I will really appreciate any helpful tip or solution to the problem.

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: Could you post the offending code? While I *think* I see what you're trying to do, actual page code would be useful. Also, "I get bugs" - what errors *specifically*?

Comment: Which code do you want me to attach? My code doesn't create those errors, the sites I get into from the HTA does. The bugs are: Javascript error.. The regular errors, like any JavaScript error. (Like this one I found online: http://www.1001bit.com/language_pack/v1.1/images/javascript-error-1.gif ) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple options to get around this problem.  The best option is to just disable the setting "display a notification about every script error" in Internet Explorer.  Since you are running an HTA you could modify the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry setting programmatically (or just manually do it once.)

The second approach is definitely more of a hack but it's how I solved the problem myself when I created a tabbed browser in an HTA before IE had tabbed browsing.  Instead of navigating to the URL in the iframe, you'll instead want to AJAX request the content, prepend a script block that sets window.onerror to a function of your chosing.  Then inject the entire contents into the iframe.  This approach will swallow any errors and give you the option of reporting them as you wish.

In addition to injecting the onerror script, you will also need to do some pre-parsing on anchors so that subsequent clicks are routed through the ajax injection handler.  This proved to be pretty complex because you essentially begin writing your own browser.  I still have the source code to the project so I'll publish it to a bitbucket repo and let you explore my approach.

Otherwise the last option is to send an email to the administrators of each site and tell them to fix their friggin bugs!!!! but I doubt that option will pan out for you :D

EDIT:

After loading up the old project I have discovered that the solution is less viable than it used to be.  The x-frame-options header directive now prevents google.com from even loading in an iframe since IE8.  And for some reason the window.onerror trap isn't catching the errors in the iframe (could be a nested iframe issue actually, but I don't have a viable solution for that.)

But I still had the option of checking the "Do not show this message again" option of the error dialog.  That makes the error dialog stop reporting issues for me and it didn't require admin privileges.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the idea.. I'll be glad to take a look of your code. The last option is the best one!! "Otherwise the last option is to send an email to the administrators of each site and tell them to fix their friggin bugs!!!! but I doubt that option will pan out for you :D" :) Thanks again